# calabash-android can not drag or swipe a slider button

Tags: automation, swipe, drag, calabash-android

i can swipe the Floating layer -> green area

using perform_action('drag_coordinates',0,1030,800,1030)  or

%x{#{default_device.adb_command} shell input swipe 0 1030 800 1030}

but can not drag or swipe the slider
using perform_action('drag_coordinates',252,1030,800,1030) and adb shell command

even hide the Floating layer

drag action does not work neither, i am sure the coordinates is correct.

[image]

[image: **enter image description here**]

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `pan` command:

```
pan("* id:'yoda_slider_window_green_block'", :right)
pan("* id:'yoda_slider_window_green_block'", :left)
```

Comment: That was exactly what i was looking for. I used it with the option hash as below

`from = {x: 1, y: 50}`  

`to = {x: 10, y: 50}`  

`pan('* {id = "seek_bar"}', :right, {:from => from, :to => to})`